# MySQLi prepared statement fails where identical regular query succeeds

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a conventional query that works just fine that looks like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT value FROM activities WHERE name = 'Drywall'");
```

This succeeds in returning a row.  However, for the purposes of diagnosing the problem I'm having with a prepared statement, I tried an identical query as a prepared statement like so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT value FROM activities WHERE name = 'Drywall'");
$stmt->execute();
```

Despite the fact these are identical query strings, $stmt->num_rows is always 0.  Why would the conventional query work, but the prepared statement not when they are the same exact query?  Also, I realize including 'Drywall' in the prepared query string runs counter to the purpose of prepared statements, but I was just trying to eliminate the possibility that bind_param() was the culprit.  So I was using bind_param() to fill in placeholders and that wasn't working either, despite my double-checking at runtime that the variable I was binding contained the correct value.

Comment: The `num_rows` method is not reliable if you haven't fetched all (or any) rows from the stmt handle. The `query` method in the first line of code is being called with the default `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT` behavior, which fetches all of the rows. Do the equivalent with the prepared statement, either using the `store_result` method, or fetching all the rows. After that, call the `num_rows` method. (`num_rows` isn't magic. It's effectively just a count of the rows fetched. You could do a loop fetching the rows and increment your own row counter variable, and you'd get an equivalent result.)

Comment: You'd need to add another line with the prepared statement to make it equivalent to the first line of code:  **`$result = $stmt->store_result();`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

before the call

```
$stmt->num_rows();
```

see last line of the descripton in the manual for $stmt->num_rows() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

Comment: I believe my problem was not first calling store_result() or fetch().  I believe either of those seems to fix the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check for proper use of the mysqli->prepare. The function depends on a parameter to be passed. It is different from passing the values ​​directly in the query but can use with another way. 
Verify the manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: You can directly pass parameters to the prepared statement or the parameters to be explicitly specified in the query construct prior to executing.

Comment: According to the docs, the query string "can include one or more parameter markers in the SQL statement by embedding question mark (?) characters at the appropriate positions."  So it doesn't have to include a parameter marker.  Though as I said in the OP, I was already doing this in the first place, but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT value FROM activities WHERE name = 'Drywall'");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

PS:

Prepared statements are Good.  I would urge you to *ALWAYS* consider using them.

But in this case, a simple query would be much more efficient (would incur fewer round trips) than a prepared statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, get_result() doesn't seem to work on my server.  It has PHP 5.3.6 installed, which should be recent enough, but I already saw in the docs it's only available with the native MySQL driver, so my server must not be running that.  I'll bet that would have fixed my problem though.  Also, regarding using prepared statements in this case, yes, this is just a simplified test for the purposes of diagnosis.  In my actual case, I'm having to guard against SQL injection attacks.